# Right way for making App Pro version in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-scheme

Well, we have got a simple application, and now we decide to make *Pro* version. Otherwise, it will have approximately 30% of changes of code and UI. My question is simply - how make this right way?

---

I've got two ideas:

I could create **additional project scheme** and set up environment for it with preproccessing, configured assets catalog, included new files, etc.

Or I could create **new project inherited from this one** and support it separately.

Both approaches has advantages and disadvantages. So I ask experienced people, what is the right way to create new *Pro* version and support both. Please, pay attention to level of changes.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just create a duplicate and change the bundle id? By that you can create another app with it, I've never do this but have you think of it?

Comment: Thank you, but this I mentioned in my second idea, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but the first way seems better if the functionality wont be changed, just added, if it change a lot as you said, 30%, i think create new one would be better :D hope someone else have better suggestion